# How can I extract number and dots from a string using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract number and dots from a string in python3 but with no success. Actually I tried using the regex search function but I get only the first number and not dots and the following number.
Here's an example of my test

```
string = "CDS             complement(129..1049)"

print(int(re.search(r'\d+', string).group()))

129
```

But actually I would like to get:

```
129..1049
```

I tried also to improve my code with:

```
print(int(re.search(r'\d+\.\.\d+', line).group()))
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '129..1049'
```

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `129..1049` is not an integer so just use: `re.findall(r'\d+\.\.\d+', line)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works fine. `re.search(r'\d+\.\.\d+', line)` returns `'129..1049'`, and so when you try to pass that string to `int()`, it fails. You'll have to manually `split` the string into its two integer parts first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use re to get all the numbers:

```
import re
str1 = "CDS             complement(129..1049)"
print(re.findall('\d+', str1))
```

I am not sure how to get the dots tho